# CXF-Servlet initial startup

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf

I have got a really basic and important question to you: My CXFServlet which is controlled by an EmbeddedTomcat deploys the webservices, when I call the url to my servlet.

How can I change that? Are there any solutions?

Comment: can you be more clear: what are you trying to change?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:cxf-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: I dont have an web.xml i try to hardcode any stuff. I also set loadonstartup on 1 ;-) Here is my EmbeddedTomcat: http://pastebin.com/HAziS0T4

Comment: so, is it still loading your servlet on access instead of loading on startup?

Comment: Yes...when i access my servlet, my application will be deployed complete.

Comment: Tomcat should load servlets on access only when load-on-startup is negative: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Wrapper.html#setLoadOnStartup(int)